# Can't get NSDictionary element

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary, nsuserdefaults

I get dictionary of dictionaries from NSUserDefaults:

```
NSUserDefaults *def = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSData *data = [def objectForKey:keyForMemory];
NSDictionary *retrievedDictionary = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
NSMutableDictionary * dictionaryFromMemory = [[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:retrievedDictionary] mutableCopy];

int flag = 0;
for (NSDictionary * dict in dictionaryFromMemory) {
    if ([[dictionary objectForKey:@"purchaseId"] isEqualToString:[dict objectForKey:@"purchaseId"]]) {
        flag = 1;
    }
}
```

This small dict must be an NSDictionary, but when I got logs inside the loop I saw the following:

[image]

I don't know why, but dict is not a dictionary, but only a string, how is it possible to take dictionary from that big dictionary, because my solution shows no signs of life(

dictionaryFromMemory is a dictionary of dictionaries, it was created and saved in such way:

```
NSMutableDictionary * bigDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

            NSDictionary * smallDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                        [dictionary objectForKey:@"purchaseId"], @"purchaseId",
                                        [dictionary objectForKey:@"price"], @"price",
                                        [dictionary objectForKey:@"enable"],@"enable",
                                        [dictionary objectForKey:@"lessons_number"],@"lessonNumber",
                                        [NSString stringWithFormat:@"0"], @"purchased",
                                        nil];

            [bigDict setObject:smallDict forKey:[dictionary objectForKey:@"purchaseId"]];


            NSMutableString * tempStr10 = [NSMutableString stringWithString:pairedData];

            NSUserDefaults *def = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
            [def setObject:[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:bigDict] forKey:tempStr10];
            [def synchronize];
```

Comment: You haven't provided enough information for us to help you. What makes you think the dictionary contains strings rather than other dictionaries? It looks like a dictionary of dictionaries to me. And how was this dictionary of dictionaries created? You need to show us that code.

Comment: @DuncanC I edited post and showed how this dictionary was created.

Comment: It iterates through the Keys for a NSDictionary, key which is a NSString.

Comment: To get the inner dictionary you need the real literal value of the key `purchaseId`, in the screenshot `com.ION.PSTutorial.b.SeriesAll`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This loop is incorrect:

```
for (NSDictionary * dict in dictionaryFromMemory) {
    if ([[dictionary objectForKey:@"purchaseId"] isEqualToString:[dict objectForKey:@"purchaseId"]]) {
        flag = 1;
    }
}
```

`dict` in this context represents the current **key** in the iteration, hence why you are seeing "com.ION.PSTutorial.b.SeriesAll".

Change the loop to retrieve the dictionary based on this key:

```
for (id key in dictionaryFromMemory) {
    NSDictionary *dict = dictionaryFromMemory[key];
    if ([dictionary[@"purchaseId"] isEqualToString:dict[@"purchaseId"]]) {
        flag = 1;
    }
}
```

I also took the liberty of converting the dictionary access to use the modern subscripting syntax.